# ASP.NET MVC and EF reference to Update Stored Procedure when doing insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, insert

I am using stored procedures to do inserts and (logical) deletes in a database that keeps all history. Updates by the application are not allowed.

I attempt to insert a new `Place` record which refers to an `AusSuburb` record. There is a bit of setup processing before I call the `context.Add` method.

(scroll right for comments)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( Place place)
{
    place.ID = Guid.NewGuid();                                                  // necessary Logic 
    place.CoreCreatingTransIdent = DbFacade.gDbFacade.Transaction.TransIdent;   // necessary Logic 
    place.CoreCreatingUserIdent = DbFacade.gDbFacade.Transaction.UserIdent;     // necessary Logic
    place.CoreName = "test";                                                    // dummy value for testing 
    DbFacade.db.Places.Add(place);                                              // add the place to context control
    EntityState x = DbFacade.db.Entry(place).State;                             // get status of place after add
    EntityState y = DbFacade.db.Entry(place.AusSuburb).State;                   // get status of suburb after add
    DbFacade.db.SaveChanges();                                                  // save changes - throws error
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

After execution, `x = Created` and `y = Unchanged`, as expected.

The `SaveChanges` throws an error that it cannot find and Update stored procedure for the `AusSuburb` entity. This is weird, because I am not trying to do an update on that table. I am doing an insert on its related table.

In normal desperation, I have provided an update stored procedure for the `AusSuburb` table which only logs its call and does nothing. The result is that the error goes away, but nothing is logged.
So, it appears that the `SaveChanges` is checking for the existence of an update procedure for the related table, but does not call it.

I can work around the problem now by creating a bunch of update procedures for each table, and configuring them in, but I feel this is probably a bug and I should report it somewhere.

Has anyone encountered this or similar?

D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into an issue caused by inserting disconnected object graphs.

When you call `DbFacade.db.Places.Add(place)`, the entire graph is marked as added so I would expect the debugger to tell you that y is `Created` after the call to `EntityState y = DbFacade.db.Entry(place.AusSuburb).State;` not `Unchanged`

So EF should be trying to insert the `AusSuburb` object...so it should be looking for an insert procedure...so that doesn't really answer why it's looking for an update procedure does it?

Bother! Do you have an insert procedure? Does it call the update procedure?

Anyway, read this and see if it helps:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the support. That article is good background. Having read it, I can add the following:
I always use just the one context for everything. My DbFacade object is a singleton ViewModel that keeps the context as a singleton context.
I use the Id approach rather than setting the complete AusSuburb object, as the article recommnds, although I have also tried with the extra line:

       place.AusSuburb = mmv.AusSuburbMgr.Goto(place.AusSuburbIdent);

Comment: again - 

place.AusSuburb = mmv.AusSuburbMgr.Goto(place.AusSuburbIdent);

The insert sp is actually a "save" sp which could be called for update or insert, but I choose to use it only as the insert, and not have any updates in the application.